# win2008 service wants to delete file : permission denied

Tags: windows, windows-services, file-permissions, delete-file

I have an old VB6 service that works on a number of Excel files. The service looks for files in a given directory, opens them and reads the contents. If everything works well the file gets a new extension ".ok", or ".err" if something went wrong.

The rename doesn't work, I get a permission denied error. So I tried copy + delete as two operations. The copy works fine, but I can't delete the file.

I'm using Windows2008R2 here. I put the files in a folder and gave "Everybody" full access (although I can't find an option that says "delete"). I even changed the file owner to "Everybody" ...

I even ran the service as Administrator who shows "Delete" in the effective rights tab.

What am I missing?

**Update** : never mind. I found that one of the processes working on the Excel file has not closed the FileStream correctly. Works now :)

Comment: How exactly did you create a Windows Service in VB 6?

Comment: It's using a control named "NTSVC.OCX". [msdn-link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/170883)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really, really make sure you're not missing some open `FileStream` or something!
(**see my edit in OP**)

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have created the windows service to run as **local service** or not. If not change it to run in local service.

Also give the folder with files full permission for the account you logged in.